# Finding the cosets of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

Struggling to understand where I'm going wrong here. I have $ G=S_3 $ and $ H = \{e, (1 2)\} $, and I want to list all the cosets with respect to H. This is what I have so far:

- Left cosets

  $eH=\{e, (12)\}=H$

  $(12)H=\{(12),(12)(12)=e\}=\{(12), e\}$

  $(13)H=\{(13),(13)(12)=(123)\}=\{(13),(123)\}$

  $(23)H=\{(23),(23)(12)=(132)\}=\{(23),(132)\}$

  $(123)H=\{(123),(123)(12)=(13)\}=\{(123),(13)\}$

  $(132)H=\{(132),(132)(12)=(23)\}=\{(132),(23)\}$
- Right cosets

  $He=H$

  $H(12)=\{(12),(12)(12)=e\}=\{(12), e\}$

  $H(13)=\{(13),(12)(13)=(132)\}=\{(13),(132)\}$

  $H(23)=\{(23),(12)(23)=(123)\}=\{(23),(123)\}$

  $H(123)=\{(123),(12)(123)=(23)\}=\{(123),(23)\}$

  $H(132)=\{(132),(12)(132)=(13)\}=\{(132),(13)\}$

I've reviewed all my calculations, and they seem right, but this results in 5 distinct sets when there should be $ \frac{|G|}{|H|} = \frac{3!}{2} = 3$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The sets are not distinct. For example $\{(13),(132)\}=\{(132),(13)\}$.

Comment: Yes, but I have both $\{(13), (132)\}$ and  $\{(13), (123)\}$.

Comment: The left and right cosets are not the same.

Comment: You shouldn't expect the cosets for the left and right action to be the same. In general if you change the action you change the cosets. So you only consider counting arguments with respect to the action, not both actions simultaneously.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: There are $3$ left cosets. There are also $3$ right cosets. But the only time that all left cosets are also right cosets is when the subgroup is normal. Here $H$ is not normal, so you don't get the same sets as both left and right cosets.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).